# I have tried to crop the the screenshot in target framework "5.0"

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, console-application

```
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray);

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
{
    Rectangle Imagecrop = new Rectangle(10, 8, 1150, 593);
    Bitmap croppedimage = new Bitmap(Imagecrop.Width, Imagecrop.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedimage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, Imagecrop.Width, Imagecrop.Height), Imagecrop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    croppedimage.Save(strFileFullPath);
}
```

When the code hits `using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))`, it starts to load further lines of code and will not work. How can I crop this?

Comment: *"it starts to load further lines of code and will not work."* - Can you clarify what you mean by this? What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt I apologize for the inconvenience. The code will really throw an exception stating that the package is not supported on this platform when it reaches the line that uses (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream)).